# ASCII ROT13 cipher results in incorrect characters

Tags: c, encryption, ascii, rot13

I have been trying to learn C and decided to do an encryption project. I want to use ROT 13 encryption for the project but I have been getting an error. The code is supposed to check the value of a char at index position `words[i]` and compare its value. If it's in the range of 97-122 (`'a'` - `'z'`), run the code and add the encryption. I learned, however, that when I want to replace a letter like 'z' and move it 6 positions, it doesn't work. Moving it 5 positions *does* work. Please see the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char words[25]= "ABC MNO XYZ";

    printf("%s \n", words);
    printf("size of 'words' is %d \n", strlen(words));

    int size_t = strlen(words);

    for (int i=0; i < size_t; i++){
        printf("%c \n", words[i]);
    }

    printf("unencrypted ends here... \n\nStarts the cipher\n");

    //converts array to lowercase for ascii purposes
    for (int i=0; i < size_t; i++){
        words[i]= tolower(words[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < size_t; i++)
    {
        char res = 'z';
        if(words[i]>=97 && words[i]<=122)
        {
            words[i] = words[i]+6;
            while(words[i] > 122)
            {
                res = words[i]-res;
                printf("The value of res is: %d\n", res);
                words[i]=96;
                words[i]= words[i]+res;
            }
        }

        //'res' ascii value equals 122
        //if words[i] is more than 122 (z), subtract 122 from it and store it in res
        //restart words[i] at position before 'a', then add res
        //not sure why but after 122 + 6 or more positions, does not reset to a char before 'a'
        //gives those weird chars at 128+ ascii locations

        printf("%c \n", words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't really use `size_t` as a variable name, it's the name of a variable type in the standard library

Comment: Subtract `'a'` from the letter. Add 13 (for rot13), and then subtract 26 if the result is >= 26. Then add `'a'` to get the final result.

Answer (score 2):

@user3386109 has already commented a solution to your problem:

> Subtract 'a' from the letter. Add 13 (for rot13), and then subtract 26
> if the result is >= 26. Then add 'a' to get the final result.

But here's an explanation of why adding 5 to `words[i]` works but 6 doesn't:

The main reason adding 5 to `words[i]` works but adding 6 doesn't is because in your case `char` is signed (range -128 to 127) so if `words[i]` (a `char`) is equal to `122`, adding 6 to it (128) overflows the range of `signed char`.

Since `words[i]` will never be negative, try using `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Last but not the least, `size_t` is a datatype in C, try to avoid using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `char` *may* have a range of [-128, 127], which is why adding 5 works, but adding 6 causes an out-of-range assignment. One solution is to first convert the char to a larger type, for example an `int`, but there is something better:

```
for (int i=0; i < size_t; i++)
{
    if (islower(words[i]))
        words[i] = (words[i] - 'a' + 13) % 26 + 'a';

    printf("%c \n", words[i]);
}
```

This takes the character, makes it a value between 0 and 25, applies the shift, takes the remainder to handle the wrapping around the alphabet, and finally adds 'a' again to convert the value back to the ASCII `'a'` to `'z'` range.
This will still implicitly convert the `char` to an `int` type, as `'a'` and `13` are `int`s, but now we no longer need an if-statement and it expresses clearly that we are using values modulo 26.

For more information on the range of `char` and type promotions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). Note that assigning an out-of-range value to a signed integer is actually *implementation-defined behavior*.

*Some additional advice*:

- The typical signature for `main`, using no parameters, is `int main(void)`.
- To use `tolower`, include the `ctype.h` header.
- Do not use an identifier called `size_t`. This is a type used in C and is `typedef`'d in [many commonly used headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).
- Using `'a'` and `'z'` makes the code easier to understand than using `97` and `122`. For checking if a `char` is lowercase, use [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower).
- The [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function returns a value of the type `size_t`. The correct format specifier for this is not `%d`, but `%zu`.